# Cypress: How can I select elements of a list that have a certain condition?

Tags: javascript, cypress

for the following html:

```
<tr xpath="1">
   <td>
      <a class="orderTemplate-name" href="/my-account/saved-carts/0000443027"> td </a>
      <div class="orderTemplate-created">
         <span> blabla </span><!----><span> blabla </span>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="orderTemplateOrderImage">
         <!----><!---->
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="orderTemplateActions">
         <button class="btn btn-commerce" id="addBtn" type="button">
            <cx-icon class="">
               <!----><!---->
               <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                  <path fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" d="blabla"></path>
               </svg>
            </cx-icon>
         </button>
         <a class="btn-icon" href="/my-account/saved-carts/0000443027">
            <cx-icon class="">
               <!----><!---->
               <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                  <path fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" d="blabla"></path>
               </svg>
            </cx-icon>
         </a>
         <button class="btn-icon" id="deleteBtn" type="button">
            <cx-icon class="">
               <!----><!---->
               <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                  <path fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" d="blabla"></path>
               </svg>
            </cx-icon>
         </button>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

i want to click on the `deleteBtn` if `orderTemplate-name` contains "automated test title". there are more than one `tr` and some have another name then "automated test title" and some have the same name. I only wanna delete all with this name.
How can I do this?

i've tried it with:

```
    cy.get('tbody tr').each(($ele) => {
        if ($ele.find('.orderTemplate-name').contains('automated test title')) {
            cy.get('#deleteBtn').click()
        }
    })
```

EDIT:

Fody's method works very well, but there is a problem with the indexing of the `<tr>` elements. the first `<tr>` is indexed first. If you delete it, it skips the next `<tr>` element and you continue with the third element.
I have attached a screenshot to make this clearer.
this is after the first element has been deleted. you can see that the next `<tr>` element is skipped.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXylt.jpg

Comment: what is `cy`? Is it a jQuery object?

Comment: cy. are the commands for the cypress testframework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ele.find('.orderTemplate-name').contains('automated test title')` gives an error

> $ele.find(...).contains is not a function

because there is no `.contains()` in jQuery.

You can use the pseudo-selector [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), but you must test the `.length` of the result

```js
if ($ele.find('.orderTemplate-name:contains("automated test title")').length) {
```

`cy.get('#deleteBtn').click()` is a bit dodgy because it always searches from the top of the document, not within the row.

If the delete action is slow to remove the row, it might still find the previous delete button because `.each()` will run quite fast.

Add `.within()` to fix that

```js
cy.get('tbody tr').each(($row) => {
  if ($row.find('.orderTemplate-name:contains("automated test title")').length) {
    cy.wrap($row).within(() => {
      cy.get('#deleteBtn').click()
    })
  }
})
```

Simpler to add `:contains()` condition inside the row selector

```js
cy.get('tbody tr:contains("automated test title")').each(($row) => {
  cy.wrap($row).find('#deleteBtn').click()
})
```

---

I agree with your comment, detached-from-DOM error is most likely due to re-render after a delete.

This function might get better results

```js
const deleteRow = (selector, rowsToDelete) => {

  if (rowsToDelete === 0) return

  // Fresh query each iteration
  cy.get('tbody tr:contains("automated test title")').eq(0)
    .as('rowDeleted')
    .find('#deleteBtn').click()
  
  // Need some way to make sure delete action has finished
  cy.get('@rowDeleted')
    .should('not.exist')

  // Do the next one
  deleteRow(selector, --rowsToDelete) 
}

const selector = 'tbody tr:contains("automated test title")'

cy.get(selector).then($rows => {  
  const rowsToDelete = $rows.length  // obtain the count
  deleteRow(selector, rowsToDelete)
})
```

Comment: `cy.get('@rowDeleted').should('not.exist')` doesnt work. The new tr which jumps to index 0 is the new `@rowDeleted`. so its in the code and the test says it exists. so the test aborted. thats strange to me because i thought that `.as` is always a unique element. 
i commented `cy.get('@rowDeleted').should('not.exist')` out and then it works pretty solid. so you helped me very much :)